# GAN: Why does adding more layers to my generator cause mode collapse? How can I fix this?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I have a GAN which I am using to generate plasma image data. My mentor has asked me to be able to change the number of layers in my GAN via cmd line argument. With that being said,  anytime I use more than 4 or 5 blocks, my generated images are all almost identical, some batches just having more noise than others. And with larger amounts of layers my images are more likely to just come out wrong(sometimes completely inverted colors). When this happens the model isn’t changing at all even when there is a loss. How can I prevent this mode collapse and why is it happening? My best guess is that all the data has an area with similar values and the GAN is just guessing that image over and over

Helpful details: Using 16000 images for training, have tried adding noise to input data, been trying to train for 100 or 200 epochs, also tried with a wasserstein loss function, seemed to have the same issue but its possible I implemented it wrong

```
class Block(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self, in_feat, out_feat, normalize=True):
       super(Block, self).__init__()
       self.layers = nn.ModuleList()
       self.layers.append(nn.Linear(in_feat, out_feat))
       if normalize:
           self.layers.append(nn.BatchNorm1d(out_feat, 0.8))
       self.layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True))

   def forward(self, z):
       img = z
       for layer in self.layers:
           img = layer(img)
       return img

class Generator(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
       super(Generator, self).__init__()

       spacing = (1024 - 128)/opt.layers
       self.block_modules = nn.ModuleList()
       self.block_modules.append(Block(opt.latent_dim, 128, normalize=False))

       current_size = 128
       prev_size = current_size
       for i in range(1, opt.layers):
           current_size = 128 + (i * spacing)
           self.block_modules.append(Block(int(prev_size),int(current_size)))
           prev_size = current_size

       self.block_modules.append(nn.Linear(int(current_size), int(np.prod(img_shape))))
       self.block_modules.append(nn.Tanh())
    

   def forward(self, z):
       img = z
       for layer in self.block_modules:
           img = layer(img)
       img = img.view(img.size(0), *img_shape)
       return img

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()

        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(int(np.prod(img_shape)), 512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(512, 256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(256, 128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(128, 64),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(64, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
        )

    def forward(self, img):
        img_flat = img.view(img.size(0), -1)
        validity = self.model(img_flat)

        return validity

adversarial_loss = torch.nn.BCELoss()

generator = Generator()
discriminator = Discriminator()

optimizer_G = torch.optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=opt.lr, betas=(opt.b1, opt.b2))
optimizer_D = torch.optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=opt.lr, betas=(opt.b1, opt.b2))

Tensor = torch.cuda.FloatTensor if cuda else torch.FloatTensor

for epoch in range(opt.n_epochs):

    for i, (imgs, _) in enumerate(dataloader):

        if opt.noise is not None:
            ns = torch.normal(mean=0.0, std=imgs.detach()*opt.noise)
            imgs = imgs + ns
        

        valid = Variable(Tensor(imgs.size(0), 1).fill_(1.0), requires_grad=False)
        fake = Variable(Tensor(imgs.size(0), 1).fill_(0.0), requires_grad=False)

        # Configure input
        real_imgs = Variable(imgs.type(Tensor))

        optimizer_G.zero_grad()

        # Sample noise as generator input
        z = Variable(Tensor(np.random.normal(0, 1, (imgs.shape[0], opt.latent_dim))))

        # Generate a batch of images
        gen_imgs = generator(z)

        g_loss = adversarial_loss(discriminator(gen_imgs), valid)

        g_loss.backward()
        optimizer_G.step()

        #  Train Discriminator
        optimizer_D.zero_grad()

        # Measure discriminator's ability to classify real from generated samples
        real_loss = adversarial_loss(discriminator(real_imgs), valid)
        fake_loss = adversarial_loss(discriminator(gen_imgs.detach()), fake)
        d_loss = (real_loss + fake_loss) / 2


        d_loss.backward()
        optimizer_D.step()
```

Comment: Have you tried convolutional layers? I think they should work better for this data, particularly if your data is consistently-sized. As another note, rather than using opt everywhere, your model classes should accept these arguments in their __init__ functions. It helps with readability and ease-of-use.

Comment: @jhso I have not yet, but I was curious to if that could help. I'm pretty new to neural networks so I wasn't sure how convolutional layers may help. I'll try that and get back to you, thanks!